# Primefaces datatable and ViewScoped

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, view-scope

I'm using primefaces 5.0 on wildfly 8.2.0 (mojarra 2.2.8).

I tried to use a simple primefaces datatable with expansion but each time I expand a row, my backed bean `@PostConstruct` is triggered (which reloads the data which nullifies the use of `@ViewScoped` in the first place).

I've seen other questions on stackoverflow about this problem but no solution worked for me:

- I'm using JSF 2.2+
- I'm not using any JSTL tags
- I disabled partial state saving in web.xml
- I tried using different `@ViewScoped` (bean, view and even omnifaces'one)

My bean:

```
@Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> things;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initializing...");
        this.things = Arrays.asList("michael", "david", "paul");
    }

    public List<String> getThings() {
        return this.things;
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:dataTable value="#{testBean.things}" var="thing">
            <p:column>
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{thing}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:rowExpansion>
                <h:outputText value="#{thing}" />
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried using `@ManagedBean` instead?

Comment: I tried using `@ManagedBean` combined with each `@ViewScoped`, no combination solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work, `<p:dataTable>` has to be inside a `<h:form>`.